# Can't create embedded canvas app for Power Apps, not found in tenant

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, cds, powerapps-modeldriven

I have an model-driven app. Trying to extend with Canvas Apps.

I follow instructions for creating (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/embedded-canvas-app-guidelines#enable-an-embedded-canvas-app)

I tap 'Customize' to generate the PowerApp but keep getting this error message:

[image: failed classic]

Have tried all browsers.

Using the classic designer was failing me, so I tried the updated viewer.

Never creates.

[image: failed regular]

Another error message:
[image]

Edge:InPrivate
[image]

Comment: Looks like cred7_title attribute is missing, is that an app name?

Comment: @ArunVinoth the app should be being generated by the system. That's the name that was being requested to create.

Comment: I have multiple tenants. Even if I log into another disconnected tenant and try.. it gives me an error on my original tenant.

Comment: Looks like SSO messing up. Can you log out in browser and close all of them before opening a new session. Did you try incognito?

Comment: Still not seeing any success with this. I've tried on another machine. Closed. Reset. Logged out of everything I can think of.

Comment: Must I create the App first then link it? I dont understand how to map the AppID..

Comment: Okay, I guess I misunderstood. I thought apps would be generated, it seems I have to make it first, then link everything. That seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: last time when I did, I could create canvas app from Model driven app and it automatically links back, not sure about the issue you’re facing.